# How can I animate the cornerRadius property of a UIView and the size using a UIView.animate (with spring) method and have the spring effects match?

Tags: ios, swift, spring, animation, uiview

I am using a

```
UIView.animate(..., usingSpringWithDamping: 0.4, initialSpringVelocity: 5, ...)
```

method to animate a `UIView` (with the `layer.cornerRadius` set to 1/2 its `frame.size.height`) to scale in place (or while moving).

Since

```
UIView.animate(..., usingSpringWithDamping: 0.4, initialSpringVelocity: 5, ...)
```

does not support the animation of a layer property. I tried creating a

```
CASpringAnimation(keyPath: "cornerRadius")
```

with the same values for dampening and velocity. However, the animations were out of sync.

Is there a way to animate the size of a circle `UIView` and animate the `layer.cornerRadius` property USING THE SPRING EFFECT (so that the bounce effect occurs on both the `cornerRadius` and size of the circle)?

Comment: `cornerRadius` was added as an animatable property for `UIView` block-based animation in iOS 11. If you are deploying to iOS 11, `self.mySubView.layer.cornerRadius = 20` will be animated if set in a `UIView.animate` block. See here for more information https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/230/.

Comment: My Xcode only allows up to 10.3 for deployment (its fully up to date), how can I enable 11? @beyowulf

Comment: If you have an apple developer account you can down load it https://developer.apple.com click on the "Download GM Seeds" `div`. Or wait a day or two and it should be on the mac app store.